# Apache site does not load without http or https in front of it

Tags: php, apache, url, digital-ocean, lamp

when I do not include the http:// or https:// prefix, my site does not load.

For example, these don't load:
`example.com` , `www.example.com`

But this does:
`https://example.com`, `http://example.com`, `http://www.example.com`, `https://www.example.com`

I am using Apache as my webserver, and here is my sites-available conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I do have an SSL Cert, generated by certbot.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So in your vHost configuration for http / Port 80, you just redirect to https. Why do you have the additional stuff there? Is you site even enabled (you quoted from sites-available). Why do you have these RewriteConditions in there? The whole configuration will only apply to example.com and www.example.com, so no need to check this again. I cannot, however, find an obvious mistake. Can you show the config for SSL / https / Port 443? What does your Browser do when you try it without http or https? Inspect the network tab of the Dev Tools and watch for redirects.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```